# Using fscanf in C, getting strange outputs

Tags: c, arrays, file, pointers, scanf

I'm trying to read an file using `fscanf` but ain't getting it to work as I have expected. as I'm new to C the problem might be my own understanding, but either ways I'm in need of some help.

I got an file whit the flowing structure:

```
3
one word 7
flying horse 11
nice guy 7
```

the first line is telling me how many lines after this one that exist in the file
the other lines are holdein 2 words and one int, all separated by a space.
I'm trying to, using fscanf to read the file, this is how I'm doing it:

```
    // get number of lines
    int Number_of_objects_in_file;
    fscanf(MYFILE_File, "%d", &Number_of_objects_in_file);

    //creat 2 arrays to use
    char *Array_of_words[Number_of_objects_in_file][2];
    int *Array_of_int[Number_of_objects_in_file];

    //creat needed variables
    int x = 0;
    int g = Number_of_objects_in_file;

    //read all lines
    while (x < g){
        char *Temp1 = malloc(42*sizeof(char));
        char *Temp2 = malloc(42*sizeof(char));
        int *Temp3 = malloc(3*sizeof(int));
        fscanf(MYFILE_File,"%s %s %d",Temp1,Temp2,Temp3);
        Array_of_words[x][0] = Temp1;
        Array_of_words[x][1] = Temp2;
        Array_of_int[x] = Temp3;
        printf("name added: %s, 2:nd name added: %s and Array_of_int: %d \n",Array_of_words[x][0], Array_of_words[x][1], Array_of_int[x]);
        x++;
    }
fclose(Map_File);
```

the print statement are printing the names correctly, but when i try to print the int it don't give the correct answerer, instead i get an random number out-printed
example*(of one line)*:

```
name added: one, 2:nd name added: word and Array_of_int: 463455
```

and it is supposed to look like this:

```
name added: one, 2:nd name added: word and Array_of_int: 7
```

. I can't figure out where I'm doing something wrong, hope you guys can help me.

*I'm using -std=c99 -Wall*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you declared your `Temp3` variable as an `int*` instead of an `int`, which was really unneeded since you only want to read a single value. Then, when you print this variable, it's printing the memory location instead of the value that was read.

Either change your declaration to `int` and stop `malloc()`ing this variable or print `Temp3[0]` instead.